# avconv and nodejs: Simple command dont work

Tags: node.js, spawn, avconv

I worked using `avconv` a lot of times. I've been trying to execute a simple command :
 `avconv -y -i my_videos/the_video.mov -filter:v "setpts=5.0*PTS" my_videos/slowed_video.mov`. This command like this works always in my command line.

In node :

```
spawn("avconv", ["-y", 
            "-i","my_videos/the_video.mov",
            '-filter:v', '"setpts=5.0*PTS"',
            "my_videos/slowed_video.mov"]);
```

but this not working. What i doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a stacktrace or any error that pops up?

Comment: `setpts=5.0*PTS` shouldn't be quoted, and you should attach event listeners to the returned process (or have it inherit the Node process’s standard output/error – see [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)) to find out what's going on.

Comment: no, this simply dont work. When i run my app, i've been trying to do `on('exit', function(){console.log("saved!")})` and the terminal shows me the message "saved!" but the video isn't saved.

Comment: @ryan i try removing the quotes but dont work

Comment: @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia: You aren't checking the exit code. Read the documentation.

Comment: ohh! reading the docs using the `.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
          console.log('stderr: ' + data);
        });` i check the error!!